# Python - Arabic conversion not proper

Tags: python, email, unicode, pyqt, arabic

I am working on a project where Arabic language  is used and I am using pyqt for the same.
There is a text box in which I enters in Arabic then take that Arabic in a variable and read it using python. I have tried using UTF-8 as well but didn't worked.

For example I am entering

> بسم الله الرحمن الرحيم

in the text box but when I read content of that box, I get the variable something as:

> ???? ????? ????

If I do not use the Unicode, then it gives me error as

> ASCII code cannot encode characters.

How get same print variable in Arabic as entered in box ?

---

code is :

```
    item=dir(self.listWidget.selectedItems())
    item=self.listWidget.currentItem()
    content=self.textEdit.toPlainText()
    content = unicode(content, "utf-8")
    FROMADDR = ""
    LOGIN = FROMADDR
    PASSWORD = ""
    TOADDRS = str(item.text())
    SUBJECT = "Invitation"


    msg = ("From: %s\r\nTo: %s\r\nSubject: %s\r\n\r\n"
    % (FROMADDR, ", ".join(TOADDRS), SUBJECT) )
    msg += ((u"%s")%content)#"some text\r\n" 
    server = smtplib.SMTP('smtp.gmail.com', 587)
    server.set_debuglevel(1)
    server.ehlo()
    server.starttls()
    server.login(LOGIN, PASSWORD)
    server.sendmail(FROMADDR, TOADDRS, msg)
    server.quit()
```

Comment: which version of python are you using ? there are a lot of difference in unicode character handling between python 2 and python 3.

Comment: @thomas : its simple to test as u can take command prompt and try adding/pasting a arabic word as string, it will show u as ??????

Comment: @sam: That depends on what operating system you're using. In Linux, I can get arabic characters at a terminal no problem.

Comment: @sam: I thought it might be Windows. But PyQt should still be able to work with unicode.

Comment: @thomas : I am not able to do. I have searched and tried but not get answers. so posted it here. :(

Comment: @sam: You might want to show some code.

Comment: It's almost certainly getting the correct value, it's just that the Windows terminal can't display it. If you display it in another Qt widget, you should see the Arabic.

Comment: @thomas : i am displaying that in email. I will show the code

Comment: @sam: There's an edit link beneath your question which you can use to add your code. Don't post edits as answers.

Comment: This is probably an issue with sending the email. I've not done anything with that. You might want to look at the `email` package: http://docs.python.org/library/email.html#module-email

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the appropriate [email package](http://docs.python.org/library/email.html) classes to ensure the encoding is done properly:

```
from email.mime.text import MIMEText
from email.header import Header
...

LOGIN = ''
PASSWORD = ''
SUBJECT = u'Invitation'
FROMADDR = u''
TOADDRS = unicode(self.listWidget.currentItem().text())
CONTENT = unicode(self.textEdit.toPlainText())

encoding = 'utf-8'

msg = MIMEText(CONTENT, 'plain', encoding)
msg['Subject'] = Header(SUBJECT, encoding)
msg['From'] = Header(FROMADDR, encoding)
msg['To'] = Header(TOADDRS, encoding)

server = smtplib.SMTP('smtp.gmail.com', 587)
server.set_debuglevel(1)
server.ehlo()
server.starttls()
server.login(LOGIN, PASSWORD)
server.sendmail(FROMADDR, [TOADDRS], msg.as_string())
server.quit()
```

Answer (score 1):

This is a problems with Windows command prompt. It is not able to reliably display Unicode characters. You need to use an IDE such as IDLE to display and verify your output.

There is more information in this question [Outputting unicode characters in windows terminal](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1725237/outputting-unicode-characters-in-windows-terminal) and in some of the links that they give.