# Python. Chess symbol in windows cmd

Tags: python, windows, unicode, console-application

How to print chess symbol in windows cmd?

```
print '♛'
```

I got 'тЩЫ'.

Comment: Here is an alternative:  `print 'Q'`  ;)

Comment: @wim: Heh, reminds me of DOS.

Comment: ☥♓⚒, but i need symbol, not letter =)

Comment: Which is not possible on Windows cmd. The terminal itself does not support it.

Comment: @NiklasB., yes it does if you issue a `chcp 65001` command first. And as of Python 3.3 it's supported by Python.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Windows Cmd window uses [Code Page 437](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_page_437) which doesn't contain any chess characters.

```
>>> print ''.join([chr(x) for x in range(256)])
 ☺☻♥♦
♫☼►◄↕‼¶§▬↨↑↓→←∟↔▲▼ !"#$%&'()*+,-./0123456789:;<=>?@ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ[\]
^_`abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz{|}~⌂ÇüéâäàåçêëèïîìÄÅÉæÆôöòûùÿÖÜ¢£¥₧ƒáíóúñÑªº¿⌐¬½¼¡
«»░▒▓│┤╡╢╖╕╣║╗╝╜╛┐└┴┬├─┼╞╟╚╔╩╦╠═╬╧╨╤╥╙╘╒╓╫╪┘┌█▄▌▐▀αßΓπΣσµτΦΘΩδ∞φε∩≡±≥≤⌠⌡÷≈°∙·√ⁿ²
■
```

Python 3.3 just added the ability to use code page 65001 which is UTF-8. Use the command `chcp 65001` before running Python.

Comment: @MarkTolonen, very good point. Doesn't change anything though, as I doubt any other code pages used by cmd include chess symbols.

Answer (score 2):

You have a couple of options that I can see, an easy one and a hard one...

1. Use an alternative terminal than windows `cmd`.  I like [console](http://sourceforge.net/projects/console/).
2. Launch the console using a [Shell Link (.LNK) file](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb776891%28VS.85%29.aspx), which allows
   you to [specify a font](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd871305%28PROT.10%29.aspx).  You might not get all of unicode, but other fonts definitely have better support for funny characters than the default.  (Stolen from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1726046/674039) answer).